# What is the reason of designing an onAnimationCancel() in Animator.AnimatorListener?

Tags: android, animation

Android SDK [Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html#cancel()) shows:

> `public void cancel ()`
>
> Cancels the animation. Unlike `end()`, `cancel()`
> causes the animation to stop in its tracks, **sending an
> `onAnimationCancel(Animator)` to its listeners, followed by an
> `onAnimationEnd(Animator)` message.**

To call some method only when the animation is not cancel.
Here is a sample from AOSP`s DeskClock：

```
rotateAnimatorY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    private boolean mIsCanceled = false;

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        mIsCanceled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        if (!mIsCanceled) {
            view.setRotation(0);
        }

        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
    }
});
```

**onAnimationCancel()** only set a **mIsCanceled** flag, all work are done in **onAnimationEnd()**.
Combine END status and CANCEL status, there are at most 3 type of work need to be done in all cases:

```
a), cancel & end. These work can live in **onAnimationEnd()**    
b), cancel &!end. These live in **onAnimationCancel()**    
c), !cancel & end. These are annoying.
```

For c), You have to involve a flag like **mIsCanceled**.

I search through the AOSP apps and have not find any benefit on making a separate method of **onAnimationCancel()**. Most of them just "Do nothing" or duplicate of the onAnimationEnd() codes.

Why not merge the cancel flag into `onAnimaitonEnd`:

abstract void   onAnimationEnd(Animator animation, boolean canceled)

IMOP, it is more elegant & light weight.

What is the reason of designing an `onAnimationCancel()` in `Animator.AnimatorListener`?

Comment: @Luksprog I suggest redesign the onAnimationEnd() like I posted.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question too well. My assumption is that they wanted to clearly separate the two events.